# Getting difficulty in passing Object from one Activity to another

Tags: android

I want to pass Object of one activity to another but i am not able to do that.The problem is the eclipse is putting the Object which i want to pass in red clause.This is the code i am using:

```
    DatabaseHandler1 db1 = new DatabaseHandler1(SecureMessagesActivity.this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SecureMessagesActivity.this,ShowTheFoldersInSdCard.class);
    intent.putExtra("id",(int)id);
    intent.putExtra("MyClassObject", db1);
```

In the last line,it is showing problem in db1.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't send SQLiteOpenHelper through intent. You can create it in second activity. Or create it in Application class.

Comment: Actually i have created  it in Application class and want to send its object to another activity.

Comment: Create object of SqliteOpenHelper in other activity & use there.

Comment: @user1726619 if you have it in Application then make it public and static like I said in my answer and call it through Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send only id through intent like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecureMessagesActivity.this,ShowTheFoldersInSdCard.class);
intent.putExtra("id",(int)id);
```

And in another activity create Helper object like this

```
DatabaseHandler1 db1 = new DatabaseHandler1(SecondActivity.this);
```

If you want to have only one instance of your Helper through whole Application, i think you should create class extending `Application` and create Helper object there like this

```
DatabaseHandler1 db1 = new DatabaseHandler1(YourApplicationClass.this);
```

You have to make it `public` and `static`. Then in every Activity you can call it like this

```
YourApplicationClass.db1.doSomething();
```